# How to send a request to the server every minute in service-worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Tried through periodicSync but it doesn't work:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined`

And this documentation says periodicSync not supported anywhere:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/periodicSync

Is it possible to implement this?:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
   while (true) {
     //timer 1 min
     //POST query
}
});
```

And so that when the reopen browser requests keep on?

Comment: PeriodicSync hasn't been implemented anywhere. May I ask your usecase? Are you completely sure this needs to happen in the SW?

Comment: I need to do background requests to the server with a certain periodicity when the browser tab is closed and when the browser restarts. Outside of SW, this definitely cannot be done ...

Comment: Just an opinion, but this is a very bad idea. You basically want to drain the user's battery. The service worker will be terminated after a period of no active clients, so this wont work.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
```

This error isn't related to periodicSync it's related to registration of Service Worker.

So a more systematic approach that is cross-browser would use the fetch API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

To do it

```
 self.addEventListener('THE_EVENT_TO_BE_USED', event => {
    setInterval(function() {
        try {
            const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api';
            // The data we are going to send in our request
            let data = {
                name: 'Sara'
            }
            // The parameters we are gonna pass to the fetch function
            let fetchData = {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
                headers: new Headers()
            }
            const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
            registration.backgroundFetch.fetch(url, fetchData).then(function(data) {
                // Handle response you get from the server
            }).catch(function(error) {
                // If there is any error you will catch them here
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }, 60000);
});
```

Comment: sorry i forgot let me change the answer